# Recycler view scrolling performance slows down with different viewtype for each row

Tags: android

I have 10 viewtypes in recycler view all come only once. while scrolling on it has lags and wont scroll smoothly.

```
@Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = null;
        switch (viewType) {

            case DashboardCard.TYPE1:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.task_checklist_dashboard_item, parent, false);
                return new TaskCheckListHolder(view);
            case DashboardCard.TYPE2:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.g_dashboard_item, parent, false);
                return new GItemViewHolder(view);
            case DashboardCard.TYPE3:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.w_dashboard_item, parent, false);
                return new WItemViewHolder(view);
            case DashboardCard.TYPE4:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.p_dashboard_item, parent, false);
                return new PItemHolder(view);
            case DashboardCard.TYPE5:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.f_item, parent, false);
                return new FtemHolder(view);
            case DashboardCard.TYPE6:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.other_dashboard_items, parent, false);
                return new OtherItemHolder(view);
            case DashboardCard.TYPE7:
                    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.pn_dashboard_item, parent, false);
                    return new MItemViewHolder(view);
            case DashboardCard.TYPE8:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.mn_card, parent, false);
                return new MNotificationItemViewHolder(view);
            case DashboardCard.TYPE9:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.walkmeter_view, parent, false);
                return new PrViewHolder(view);
            case DashboardCard.TYPE10:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.other_notification_card, parent, false);
                return new OtherItemViewHolder(view);

        }
        return null;
    }
```

each view has a custom view which had a bar graph or some other graph which is drawn using canvas methods on onDraw()

Implementation of recycler view is fine and all things are rendering but the scroll performance is very bad.

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: Agreed with @iRuth... To improve the response you get from your questions, consider doing such things as posting a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work), making your question clear in the title ,[adding necessary tags](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)... and [heading on over to the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info

Comment: added code to the question

Answer (score 0):

Without further information, it is difficult to tell where the slow parts of your code are.  Based on the fact you are doing potentially intensive drawing operations, however, you may benefit from drawing into a `Bitmap` on a background thread.  One way to implement this is to put an `ImageView` in each layout, then in `onBindViewHolder()`:

1. Clear the `ImageView` of any existing image it may already have.
2. Start a background thread (ex. `AsyncTask`) to draw the image.
3. When the background drawing is complete (ex. `onPostExecute()` in `AsyncTask`, load the bitmap into the `ImageView`.